# Using CSS transform scale maintains original positioning

Tags: css, transform

When using the `transform: scale()` property, elements that are floated next to each other act like their full-size counterparts even after the scaling.

As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/a4BMK/1/ (click the button)

Is there a property that will resize the elements, then re-float them so they are again touching each other?

By the way, the real elements I'm using are models of all different widths and heights, so simply using `width:` or `height:` across all the elements is not an easy solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, **no**, there is no CSS way of positioning based on the scaled value that I know of.

I do, however, know how you could compensate (without using any javascript) using a work around. You can use a `translateX(-25%)` in addition to the scale to position all of them next to each other. With that being said, the percents have to increase per element to compensate for the other being moved. This means that you have to use a set number of elements or perhaps a pre-processor to compensate

```
.img:nth-child(1) {
    transform: scale(.8);
}
.img:nth-child(2) {
    transform: scale(.8) translateX(-25%);
}
.img:nth-child(3) {
    transform: scale(.8) translateX(-50%);
}
.img:nth-child(4) {
    transform: scale(.8) translateX(-75%);
}
.img:nth-child(5) {
    transform: scale(.8) translateX(-100%);
}
img {
    float: left;
    transform-origin: top left;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1fL4q9y5/)

Comment: Good thinking! I also realized if I simply scaled the overall outer div instead of each individual element I could achieve my desired result.